# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA count preceeding rows that meet condition

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Let's say I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
Name                   D-List
---------------------  ------
Arnold Schwarzenegger
Bruce Willis
Dolph Lundgren
Dwayne Johnson
Jason Statham
Keanu Reeves
Samuel L. Jackson
Sylvester Stallone
Vin Diesel
```

For the `D-List` column, I'd like to count the number of proceeding rows that contains the string `"d"`. If the row doesn't contain a `"d"`, then I want it to return an empty string.

For any given row, I can get this to work with the following pseudo formula:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A<row>, "d"), COUNTIF(A<row>, "*d*"), "")
```

```
Name                   D-List
---------------------  ------
Arnold Schwarzenegger  1
Bruce Willis    
Dolph Lundgren         2
Dwayne Johnson         3
Jason Statham   
Keanu Reeves    
Samuel L. Jackson   
Sylvester Stallone  
Vin Diesel             4
```

I can turn this into an expression that can be duplicated between rows by using `INDIRECT` and `ROW`:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)d"), COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A" & ROW(A2)), "*D*"), "")
```

```
Name                   D-List
---------------------  ------
Arnold Schwarzenegger  1
Bruce Willis    
Dolph Lundgren         2
Dwayne Johnson         3
Jason Statham   
Keanu Reeves    
Samuel L. Jackson   
Sylvester Stallone  
Vin Diesel             4
```

However, if I try to stick it in an `ARRAYFORMULA`, it doesn't work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "D"), COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A" & ROW(A2:A)), "*D*"), ""))
```

```
Name                   D-List
---------------------  ------
Arnold Schwarzenegger   
Bruce Willis    
Dolph Lundgren         1
Dwayne Johnson         1
Jason Statham   
Keanu Reeves    
Samuel L. Jackson   
Sylvester Stallone  
Vin Diesel             1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "(?i)d"), COUNTIFS(
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "(?i)d"), 
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "(?i)d"), ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nice. Could be simplified a bit: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A10,"(?i)d"), COUNTIFS(A2:A10,"*d*",ROW(A2:A10),"<="&ROW(A2:A10)),))`

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't realize `COUNTIFS` was a thing.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for the simplification!